# Fabric not tracking the correct CFBundleShortVersion

Tags: google-fabric

I have my iOS released at `2.0 (655)`, and then came up with a bug fix release `2.0.2 (663)`. However, in Fabric adoption graph, I am seeing mixes of versions as below:

- 2.0 (663)
- 2.0.2 (663)

What happened?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Are you not seeing the release at all of 2.0.2 (655) or do you think we're inaccurately tracking the value?

Comment: I guess it's inaccurate, as both 663 values mentioned above show up

Comment: Hmm, strange. I'd recommend enabling debug mode: final Fabric fabric = // Objective-C
[[Fabric sharedSDK] setDebug: YES];
[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];

// Swift
Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self()])

 and check the logs to see what Crashlytics is reporting as the version number and code.

Comment: It's production env. I will try.